# XCode - Ruby on Rails Project Templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, templates, project

Where can I find project templates for Ruby on Rails to use within projects?

I am using Xcode version 3.2.2.

From what I understand, Apple stopped shipping all project templates with Xcode and made them available as optional downloads, yet I cannot find the templates for Ruby on Rails anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the "template" of a fresh rails app can change from version to version, you should use the `rails new myapp` generator command at the Terminal, and the open the result in XCode organizer.

More here: http://developer.apple.com/tools/developonrailsleopard.html